# How to find the minimum value in each table column and display a class in php

Tags: php, yql

Hi I pulled a table from an external website using **YQL**. The table contains a list of times such as: But the number of columns can change to include more columns.

```
| Name   | T1     | T2     | T3     |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| Name 1 | 23.234 | 45.234 | 16.456 |
| Name 2 | 23.389 | 44.322 | 15.222 |
| Name 5 | 22.890 | 44.221 | 15.345 |
```

What I'm trying to do is get the lowest value from each column. I've been able to get it by using this function.

```
<?php 
   $sectim = [];
   for ($st=1; $st < count($allRows); $st++) { 
       $sectim[] = $phpObj->query->results->tbody->tr[1]->td[6]->content;

   }
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($sectim); echo "</pre>";  
   echo "<pre>"; print_r(min($sectim)); echo "</pre>"; 
 ?>
```

This gives me a list of all the times in that column and gives me the minimum. What I am struggling with is how to do it in a way that I can get the minimum from each table columns given the number of columns is not fixed and can either be 3 columns 4 or even 9 columns. I'm thinking of using either another for statements to loop through all the columns but I don't know whether that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
select min(T1) as column1,min(T2) as column2,min(T3) as column3 from tabel
```

This will give you minimum value of each column.

Comment: he is not using database. Please read the question before answering it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking For build dynamic query :

```
$array = array(
   'column1' => 'T1',
   'column2' => 'T2',
   'column3' => 'T3'
);

$column_binder = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
    $column_binder[] = " min($value) as $key ";
}

$query = "SELECT ".impode(",", $column_binder)." From tabel_name";
```